# How to substitute bind variable in pl/sql developer tool

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I would like to run a SQL script in PL/SQL developer as following example.

```
variable vTest varchar2;
(exec/set) :vTest := 'ABC'
select :vTest from dual;
select :vTest ||'XYZ' from dual ;
select * from table  where columnname = :vTest;
```

Comment: "Question is self explanatory" I'm afraid it is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a Test Window.

First do a

```
grant debug connect session to <schema>
```

Then open a new Test window. Declare your bind variables at the bottom of the screen. You give them a name, a type and a value there.

Comment: You can also run the whole thing in the Command Window.  Although at that point you might as well use SQL*Plus.

Comment: How do you open a test window

Comment: From the menu: File -> New -> Test window