# Variables in where clause in Oracle PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

In ORACLE PL/SQL DEVELOPER, am I able to do the following as I could easily do in SQL Server?

```
DECLARE @EmpIDVar INT

SET @EmpIDVar = 1234

SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpIDVar
```

This seems like such a simple thing and yet it seems impossible to do in Oracle!

I know about using & in front of variables that will prompt me to enter their values but why can't I just do something like the above?

Answer (score 0):

Declare Using `VARIABLE` command

```
VARIABLE EmpIDVar NUMBER;
```

Set the value Using `EXEC` like this

```
EXEC :EmpIDVar := 1234;
```

Run the Query prefixing the variable with `colon`

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE EmployeeID = :EmpIDVar;
```

Comment: @user3359423 It works with `SQL*Plus`.. For `PL/SQL Developer`, you can try [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887848/how-to-substitute-bind-variable-in-pl-sql-developer-tool)

Comment: Tried the other answer and I couldn't get it to work. It seems that the only way you can do this in PL SQL Developer is to just use substitution variables. ie. put a &<param_name> in place of where you put your variable and PL/SQL developer will substitute for you for e.g. select * from employees where EmployeeId = &EmployeeId

Comment: Yes, but that is not executed as bind variable.. it is just like a macro. String is formed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Using Variable and select with IN clause, perhaps is more useful.

```
VARIABLE EmpIDVar NUMBER
DEFINE EmpIDVar ="123, 124"
EXEC : EmpIDVar := '& EmpIDVar'

SELECT 
  E.*
FROM Employees E
WHERE EmployeeID IN ( & EmpIDVar )
```

If not, simple replace IN with "=" and "123, 124" with "123".

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you can see another answer

[How to use variables in an Oracle PL/SQL where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666647/how-to-use-variables-in-an-oracle-pl-sql-where-clause)

```
 set serveroutput on

 DECLARE 
    EmpIDVar integer; 
    Result integer;

  BEGIN
     EmpIDVar := 2000;


     SELECT Employees_id into Result      
     FROM Employees 
     WHERE Employees_ID = EmpIDVar ;

     dbms_output.Put_line(Result); 
  end;
```

if you wanted to show all(*) you would need, to show all variables , so like i said you need as much varialbes as you fields have.